# Should I turn my iPad off to replace the MicroSIM?

Tags: ipad, hardware

Should I turn my iPad off to replace the MicroSIM card?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by "3g chip", you are referring to the iPad MicroSIM card, then no, you do not need to power off the device to switch it out. However, if you're referring to the actual 3G radio inside the iPad, my advice is to take it to an Apple store and have the repair done by an Apple technician, as operating on the device yourself is likely to void the warranty.

Comment: yes. I'm talking about microsim.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should turn off your iPad before doing anything with the innards.

Comment: I'm sure the asker meant the microSIM, not the innards. Maybe I'm expecting too much but I expect that anyone who wants to dismantle the iPad will know to turn it off first (or suffer the consequences). What did I read earlier today? *I don't mind that the gene pool doesn't have a life guard, but why are there so few sharks?*

Answer (score -1):

It always better to switch off such devices before replacing SIMs.  With the exception of USB ports found on computers, its always recommended to turn off devices before connecting or replacing cables and chips.

Comment: Everything on iOS is hot swappable, but putting the device into airplane mode prevents a network transfer from being cut short / corrupting an email perhaps. Shutting down also should be the same, but is overkill for SIM swapping.